# How to automatically restart AKS deployment based on alert?

Tags: python, azure, function, azure-aks

I would like to restart AKS deployment when alert is fired, which solution better to use for such cases and is there some official documentation how to integrate this with Azure resources?

Using Azure Automation account or Azure function.

Answer (score 1):

I would try an action group Web Hook sending a POST to Azure Devops Service hook (if you are using it) to trigger special pipelines to restart whatever you need:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/pipelines/sprint-172-update?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-21138#generic-webhook-based-triggers-for-yaml-pipelines

anyways you can try using any of these types of action types when your alert fires:

[image]